# Probability that Brownian motion makes a loop around the origin

Tags: probability-theory

Let $B$ be a complex Brownian motion started at $\epsilon > 0$. I am trying to prove that as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, the probability that $B$ makes a loop around the origin before hitting the unit circle tends to 1.

I tried looking at $\operatorname{arg} B_t$, and rescaling the problem, but neither of these seemed to get me anywhere. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $\epsilon$, by scaling, this is the probability that a Brownian motion starting at $1$ makes a loop around the origin before hitting the circle of radius $1/\epsilon$. When $\epsilon\to0$, the hitting time of the circle of radius $1/\epsilon$ goes to infinity hence, in the limit, one is after the probability that a Brownian motion starting at $1$ makes a loop around the origin, *ever*.

The conclusion then comes from a representation of the argument process of a plane Brownian motion... which you might know?